# Detect F5 browser refresh from angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, browser-refresh

Actually, I want to be able to handle page refreshing from AngularJS directly and not from plain JS with the following known solution:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   // handle the exit event
};
```

I found that we can detect it with ngRoute by using the following event listener:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
  if (!current) {
    // handle session start event
  }
});
```

But I'm not using this router for my application. I am working with angular-ui-router 1.x. And events have been deprecated in favor of transitions hooks (cf. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

I can't find a way to detect browser refresh using angular-ui-router 1.x. If anyone have an idea to do that, it would be great !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I my own solution I created directive that uses onbeforeundload native event and set it to html body. 
This give me desired ability and integrated it into angular live cycle so I can gen any service or other angular staff with it.